# Referencing page/control from ITemplate class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control in which I have a RadGrid that has dynamic TemplateField's - as they are dynamic I am using my own custom class inheriting from ITemplate. Code below:

```
    public class ApplicationHeaderTemplateItem : ITemplate
    {
        private string colName;
        public ApplicationHeaderTemplateItem(string cName)
        {
            colName = cName;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {

            HtmlTable tb = new HtmlTable();
        HtmlTableRow headerRow = new HtmlTableRow();


        //Create the textbox to display the percentage
        HtmlTableCell percentCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        RadNumericTextBox txt = new RadNumericTextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + colName;
        txt.DataBinding += txt_DataBinding;
        txt.AutoPostBack = true;
        txt.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
        percentCell.Controls.Add(txt);
        headerRow.Cells.Add(percentCell);

         --snip--
        }

        void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
```

As you can see I have a TextChanged event for my textbox. My problem is that the method is created in the context of the ApplicationHeaderTemplateItem class, so I can't access any of the controls in my user control. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sender` argument to get your `TextBox`, then you are already there since every control has a [`Page` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx).

```
void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control txt = (Control) sender;
    Page page = txt.Page;
}
```

Comment: That'd be great but as I need to get the user control object instead, it doesn't work. I.e the below:

   Applications app = (Applications)((Control)sender).Page;

           
gives me

Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Page' to 'Project.JobControls.Applications'

Comment: So `Project.JobControls.Applications` is the `UserControl` that this `TextBox` is sitting in? Try `(Project.JobControls.Applications)txt.NamingContainer;`

Comment: Yep, that's where the textbox resides and contains the method I want to call